# AWK to print the names and numbers greater than the average

Tags: shell, awk

That's the file:

```
Alpha Beta Omega 100 95 90
One Two Three Four Five 13 24 50
Yes No 70 70 70
João Édipo Schültz 40 50 60
```

The average must be set as 70, so the three numbers %3 has to be equal/greater than 70. And the answer (output) should be:

```
Alpha Beta Omega 100 95 90
Yes No 70 70 70
```

I've tried use this to isolate the numbers, but couldn't remove the letters with `~`, `^`, `\´` and stuff:

```
awk -F"[a-zA-Z=&\"]*" '{print $2,$3,$4}'
```

How may I use AWK to do this? Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to take the average of the three numbers in the line and compare to 70?

Comment: What is the result desired for a line `Yes No 69 70 70`? Print that since a value is =70 or not since the average is <70?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```sh
awk -v p=70 '{for (i=NF-3; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i < p) next} 1' file

Alpha Beta Omega 100 95 90
Yes No 70 70 70
```

Here `if ($i < p) next` will skip a record as soon as any of the last 3 columns is less than variable `p` which is set to `70` on command line.

If your numbers to be compared can be anywhere in a line then use:

```sh
awk -v p=70 '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (+$i == $i && $i < p) next} 1' file
```

Where `+$i == $i` returns true if column is numeric.

Comment: Yes `1` or any non-zero in the end would just print the line

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you are looking to print the lines if *any* value in the line is over `70` or if the average of the numbers found is over `70`?

If it is *any* value in the line:

```
awk -v x=70 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0==$i && $i>=x) {print; next}}' file
```

If it is the *average* of the numbers found:

```
awk -v x=70 '{
        sum=cnt=0
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0==$i) {cnt++; sum+=$i}
        if ((sum/cnt)>=x) print
        }' file
```

Both print:

```
Alpha Beta Omega 100 95 90
Yes No 70 70 70
```